# In ffmpeg how to keep text same location while filtering like zooming?

Tags: ffmpeg

In ffmpeg how do I keep the text in the same location while filtering? e.g. zooming

FFmpeg for linux

```
ffmpeg 
-t 5 
-i x.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]drawtext=fontfile='ariblk.ttf':text='test text':fontsize=24:x=0.23333333333333*main_w: y=0.1325*main_h:fontcolor=#000000: alpha=1,zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0]; [v0]concat=n=1:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" 
-map "[v]" 
-s "800x450" 
-t 40 ./video.mp4
```

The text is zoomed in as well but I want it to keep the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the zoom before drawing text.

```
ffmpeg 
-i x.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125:s=800x450,drawtext=fontfile='ariblk.ttf':text='test text':fontsize=24:x=0.23333333333333*main_w:y=0.1325*main_h:fontcolor=#000000: alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,format=yuv420p[v]" 
-map "[v]" 
-t 40 ./video.mp4
```

The concat is unnecessary; you only have one input.

Comment: Thank you, actually i'm using several image and this is a part of my code. I forgot concat while pasting to here this part. It worked.